# "If we didn't possess this mechanism, our surroundings would appear shadowy" - why not "had not / would have appeared"?

Tags: conditional-constructions

From [ScienceDaily](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/01/170119134546.htm):

> From a big-picture perspective, if we **didn't possess** this powerful oculomotor mechanism, particularly when blinking, our surroundings **would appear shadowy**, erratic and jittery, researchers said.

Why is it not like this:

> From a big-picture perspective, if we **had not possessed** this powerful oculomotor mechanism, particularly when blinking, our surroundings **would have appeared shadowy**, erratic and jittery, researchers said.

After all, we **do** possess this mechanism, so we should use the **had not possessed / would have appeared** to indicate the counterfactual nature of the statement, shouldn't we?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The so-called 'past' forms *did* and *would* are employed to express present counterfactuality. The corresponding real situation is expressed with 'present' forms:

> If we **do not possess** this mechanism our surroundings **will appear** shadowy.

The constructions with *HAVE* + past participle (I call this the 'sham perfect') are used to express *past* counterfactuality:

> If we **had not possessed** this mechanism (long ago), our surroundings **would have appeared** shadowy (at that time).